# Workstation discovery

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory

Is there any way to find all the workstation on the Active directory "win 2003".

without being the Domain admin?

Answer (score 1):

WinXP and up have you covered:

```
dsquery computer -limit 10000
```

That'll give you a list of all of the computer-objects in the AD tree. dsquery allows fancier filtering as well if you need it. A useful tool!

Answer (score 0):

If you are a user on the network you can use [AD Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963907) this should allow you to READ AD but it is possible you will receive an error....

If you need a list of machines on the network i  would suggest that you ask an administrator as this may break your company policy and could depending how strict the network is lose you your job...

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell can do this with one line (not sure if this works on 2003 domain though):

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter 'operatingSystem -notlike "*server*"' | FT name
```

You may need to import the activedirectory module first. So your first line in the powershell window might need to be:

```
import-module act*
```